# Django Graphene filter Foreign Model

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python

I need to filter the object my request on the back-end base on permissions.

For the following query :

```
query {
  foos {
    id
    name
    barSet {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

There are permissions on foo and bar and I need to only return some foo and some bars.

I know that I can use field lookups for foos

```or-tag-here
class FooType(DjangoObjectType):
  class Meta:
    model = Foo

class BarType(DjangoObjectType):
  class Meta:
    model = Bar

class Query(object):
  foos = graphene.List(FooType)

  def resolve_foos(self, info, **kwargs):
    # id_list = some code to create a list of ids of possible foos

    return Foo.objects.filter(id__in=id_list)
```

Say I have a list of possible bars, **how can I** do the same to **filter on bar when requested by a graphql query ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `FooType` you need to create a custom resolver for the bar field where you can apply permission filtering.  For example, assuming a manager method on `Bar` called `filter_by_user`:

```
class FooType(DjangoObjectType):
  bars = graphene.List(BarType)

  class Meta:
    model = Foo

  def resolve_bars(self, info):
      # do something to filter Bars by permissions
      return self.bar_set.filter_by_user(info.context.user)
```

Also, in Bar Meta, you might need to add `exclude_fields` for `bar_set` field if it's added automatically.